# Image could not be fitted into Webview in Android

Tags: android, image, webview

I am trying to use Webview to load an image by its URL directly.

The problem is that the image is a little bit bigger than the screen size, thus the horizontal and vertical scroll bars displayed.

I tried to set the initial scale factor to 1, but the problem still exists.

If I applied myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN), the image can just fit into the Webview. The critical drawback is that I could not use zoom control.

How to make the image just fit into the Webview ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just to set `width` attribute of img to 100% and don't set `height` attribute

```
<body >
<img id="resizeImage" src="palacezone.png" width="100%" alt="" />
</body>
```

Comment: I tried your method. The drawback is that I could not zoom in !